# What is a command that will only show me the command syntax and options?

Tags: command, options

Is there a command which will just list all the options for a given command on one or two lines and not as long and words as `man` or `info` ?

Comment: `whatis` will give you output that is basically the first line of the corresponding man page, but that typically does not contain any option synopsis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no universal answer here....as the output from a given command is the responsibility of the author of that particular program not anything in the Linux operating system or any of the shells.  In general, I try to use --help and hope for the best, but in cases of filter type programs, you might not get anything at all.

Assumming the man pages are installed, they are one of the best sources for command line information.....otherthan the source code itself.

Not all commands contain data for the info command either.